# How did Google implement Google Earth in browser?

Tags: google-maps, google-earth

I noticed that we can see Google Earth in our browser on maps.google.com now, I'm wondering how they implement it? Is it webgl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a browser plugin. Like flash or the plugins to display PDF documents in your browser. Nothing new.

Comment: Oh yes, I found it in chrome://plugins